# how to find/ incorporate forced convection in dymola

Tags: dymola

Am doing a project which is about thermal management of the 18650 lithium-ion pack. I am currently simulating the model under natural convection. But I am supposed to run under forced convection. How/ where can we find forced convection in Dymola

Comment: You need to provide more information, at least the model you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection but you have to provide a value/equation for the thermal conductance Gc using a correlation from a textbook that fits the flow situation e.g. flow around / along a cylinder.